# [Vue][ElementUI] Can I use the variable name to create a component

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

There is a NavMenu and a Main component.Once I click the the menu,I want to create a component in the Main component.
 And I don't know what component will be created until it is clicked.

```
main.vue:
<el-tabs v-model='xxx'>
    <el-tab-pane>[there will be the component]</el-tab-pane>
</el-tabs>
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use the variable name to create a component?

#### Yes, it's called `Dynamic Components`

Learn more `Dynamic Components`  [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)

You can use attribute `is` to create a dynamic component.

Learn more `:it` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is)

```
<component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```